# Realm.io: Are write / read operations executed on the main thread?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am curious if read / write operations like this are executed on the main thread:

```
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(myDog)
}
```

This is important because I want to run operations directly after something has been read or written to realm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block is executed on the same thread as the thread that calls the `write()` method synchronously. In different words, if you call `write()` on the main thread, the block will be executed on the main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("background", nil)) {

  // Some operations in a background thread ...

  try! realm.write {
    // this block will be executed on the background thread
  }
}
```

If you'd like to execute the write operation on the main thread, you may need to dispatch to the main thread as needed.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_queue_create("background", nil)) {

  // Some operations in a background thread ...

  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    try! realm.write {
      // this block will be executed on the main thread
    }
  }
}
```